# How to rename the row index in Python Pandas data frame for a large data sets?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a large dataset which is having 68000 rows. When I have imported, pandas have already assigned row index starting from 0 to 68,000. And, I did sorting for the columns (Ascending order) and inplace the same. Now the row index has assigned the particular row number. I want to reassign the row number to 0 to 68,000. Please see the below screenshot. I have tried the documentation but not successful.

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQOPT.png)

[df.tail()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUS4y.png)

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Much appreciated